# How to run a Docker container but not copy a password file to assemble image, other options?

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile

Since this is work related I will do more pseudo code but here is the problem.  I am building an image to run a spring web app inside of a container with a `Dockerfile`.  This works fine locally when I run my tomcat server from eclipse and also inside the container with docker run.  So here is the issue. When I build my image with the docker file I create a config folder:

```
RUN mkdir -p /pathToConfig/config
```

I then copy my password file into this config folder:

```
COPY ./locationOfPassowrdFile/passwords.properties /pathToConfig/config 

EXPOSE myPort

CMD java -jar -DpropertySource="file:/pathToConfig/config/passwords.properties" ....more launchCode...... WARFILENAME.WAR
```

I have researched secrets but I am not able to connect the dots.  For example, I was wondering is there a way to create a secret with the `passwords.properties` file and then when I launch the APP with `CMD` .... can I link it there?  Seems easy but I have not been able to bring these ideas together. Also, I am not using K8 or Swarm so not sure if that is an issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.. but couldn't you just volume mount the file into the container?

[Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: This worked for me, followed the secrets section on the K8 website and success.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need to pass some secret configuration to the docker container at runtime.
You **can** use docker secrets (even if you don't run a swarm) by creating a compose file:

Project structure:

```
 |- Dockerfile
 |- docker-compose.yml
 |- pathToConfig
    |- config
      |- passwords.properties
```

`docker-compose.yml` contents:

```
version: "3.6"

services:

  my_service:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    entrypoint: 'java -jar -DpropertySource="file:/run/secrets/my_secret" ...'
    secrets:
       - my_secret

secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: /pathToConfig/config/passwords.properties
```

Run the following command from the project's root to build the image and run the container:

```
docker-compose up --build my_service
```

At runtime, `passwords.properties` is mapped to `/run/secrets/my_secret` and the application will be able to read
the configuration from that location. More about secrets configuration [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets)

If it looks complicated you have other options:

- configuration files in docker volumes
- passing environment variables at runtime. See [Set environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)

Hope it  helps